# In which Bootstrap folder are the modals usually located?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have this modal that opens here:
http://www.quizuri.ro/quizzes/test/1036?embed=true

(just click start and wait 5 seconds)

and I want to make some changes to it but I don't know where it is located in my site folders [http://i.imgur.com/3uUCrQ6.png](https://i.imgur.com/3uUCrQ6.png) . The site is made with bootstrap and Laravel. Does anyone know how I can find it? Thanks.
PS: yes, I don't know bootstrap or Laravel.

Comment: That doesn't look like Laravel, unless it's a very very old and insecure version I'm not familiar with. It's certainly not L4 or L5. The code could be anywhere - search the project for the modal code (any IDE can do this).

Comment: Nobody can tell just from a directory list and it could be 100% created using script also. As mentioned a full project search should help

Comment: How can I do a search and find it? thanks

Comment: @LucianBarligea - I suggest you to use for example Notepad++, you can do a "search in folder" and you select the root of your webproject. Search for a specific phrasename, but that's not 100% guarantee

Comment: I am using Coda. Any idea how to search on that?

Comment: Look in the various menus, or try right-clicking on a folder to search it.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to search into your source code for `" class="modal"` "

Comment: This does not answer the question and might be better suited as a comment which you can place ones you have sufficient reputation.